# Methods to encourage good behaviour when using shared servers?

Tags: teamwork, development-environment

This question was prompted by a comment left on another question pointing to this article.

[What Is Clean Code?](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1235624&seqNum=6)

I was thinking about how that sentiment can be applied to shared resources (servers, etc).

What are some of the ways you've found that work to ensure that when others use a shared server they clean up after themselves?

- Delete files / folders after one time use (after a fix or upgrade)
- Leave the desktop clean of crap
- Don't install software that they can use on their desktop
- Don't create filesystem shares not needed for the solution

Yes, this applies mostly to a windows server environment, in a team of developers + support staff of about 25.

I know there are a few ways to tackle the problem, so what have you found that works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is very similar to "dirty toilet" problem. The classic approach is a shield "please leave the cabin in a condition in which you would like to find it" (forgive me my poor English).

Combining this with a simple monitoring/mailing scripts should work fairly well.

Comment: Thanks, I like the idea of the monitoring scripts. Setup a set of "allowed" folders/files and then alert after 24 hours (or so) for stuff outside that. :)